# Boolean if statement

Tags: java, bluej

```
public class Health
{
    boolean dependency;
    String insuranceOwner = "";
    static final int basicHealthFee = 250;
    static final int healthDiscount = 20;

    public Health(boolean dependent, String insurance)  
    {  
        dependency = dependent;  
        insuranceOwner = insurance;  
    }

    public double computeCost()
    {
        double healthFee;
        if (dependency == true)
        {
            healthFee = basicHealthFee - (basicHealthFee * (healthDiscount/100.0));
        }
        else 
        {
            healthFee = basicHealthFee;
        }

        return healthFee;
    }
}

 Health h34 = new Health(true, "Jim");         
 System.out.println("discount price: " + h34.computeCost());
```

When I enter in true as a parameter to the constructor, my computeCost method still runs the block as if dependency were to == false. Is there any reason why?

Comment: There's an unknown - what happens between the time the object is instantiated and this method is called?  As it stands, if `dependency`, then the first portion *must* be executed.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program?

Comment: Are you using the same instance which was created to call this method? Is dependency `static`? Lots of possibilities. Post the code where you're creating the instance of `Health` and calling the method `computeCost()`.

Comment: @Makoto Time *between* the constructor being called and a method being called? How does one achieve that?

Comment: could you write more detail when you initiate the object of Health Class?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: New up an object, do some other ancillary work with it, then call the specific method?

Comment: Just posted the whole code, sorry about forgetting the first portion.

Comment: @RyanSisson:  There's more.  Post your `main()` method.  That code alone doesn't tell us the appropriate chain of events.  Don't let the locked question scare you; this will give you an appropriate amount of time to get the question in an answerable state.

Comment: Provide some more detail about how you are creating object of your Health class and when you are calling method computeCost()...

Comment: This is the entire class, so all of the relevant methods should be in that code. I'm relatively new to java so I may not fully understand what you're looking for. However, for the tester class that calls upon this computeCost method looks like     Health h34 = new Health(false, "Jim");
      System.out.println("discount price: " + h1.computeCost());

Comment: So...you're saying that you newed the object with `false` and it's running through with the `false` case?  Why is this a problem?  It's doing *exactly* what you told it to.

Comment: Sorry, I was cycling through true's and false's when trying to find the issue, and that was the last one I tried. However, even when it says:  Health h34 = new Health(true, "Jim"); System.out.println("discount price: " + h1.computeCost());         it will still run the false block of code from my if statement.

Comment: No, wait.  I see it now.  Let's get one more reopen vote so I can answer this.

Comment: @Makoto It's all you.

Comment: I don't think it is running the false case every time. Your problem is integer truncation.  integer math of 20/100 == 0, so basicHealthFee is always multiplied by zero.

Comment: Thanks for the catch Paul, however even after switching it to h34, it still runs the false block

Comment: @RyanSisson Please edit the question to include the calling code (so other people can understand what's going on without reading all the comments).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're falling victim to integer division.  `20/100 == 0`, and anything multiplied by that is 0.  To get around that, change your `static final int` declarations to doubles.

```
static final double basicHealthFee = 250D;
static final double healthDiscount = 20D;
```

That `D` defines a [double literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 4):

You need to define basicHealthFee and healthDiscount as `double`.  Since you've defined them as integers you have the equation:  `healthFee = basicHealthFee - (basicHealthFee * (healthDiscount/100));` which becomes `basicHealthFee - ( basicHealthFee * (20/100))` which becomes `basicHealthFee - (basicHealthFee * 0)` -> `basicHealthFee - 0`.

The if statement taking its value from your constructor is correct.

Comment: Thanks par, that was the issue. Also thanks to everyone else who helped try and answer the problem

Comment: No problem.  Since you're new please mark one of the answers as correct when you get a reply that helps.  Makoto posted first so give it to him (or her as appropriate ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not related to boolean.  It is due to the division of integers.  Please change the program as follows.
static final double healthDiscount = 20d;
static final double basicHealthFee = 250d;

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;

public class Health {
    boolean dependency;
    String insuranceOwner = "";
    static final double basicHealthFee = 250d;
    static final double healthDiscount = 20d;

    public Health(boolean dependent, String insurance) {
        dependency = dependent;
        insuranceOwner = insurance;
    }

    public double computeCost() {
        double healthFee;
        if (dependency == true) {
            healthFee = basicHealthFee
                    - (basicHealthFee * (healthDiscount / 100.0d));
        } else {
            healthFee = basicHealthFee;
        }

        return healthFee;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Health h34 = new Health(true, "Jim");
        System.out.println("discount price: " + h34.computeCost());
    }
}
```